# Converting a Large list of lists with 'data points listed in lists' into a data frame in r

Tags: r, list

I have exhaustively researched on how to convert a complex list to a data frame - but it seems my case is fairly unique:

Problem:
I have a Large list with lists of several variables, whose observations (data points) are further listed as a list.

Below is the structure of a representative list 1 of the multiple primary lists;

`:List of 5
 ..$ type : chr "time"
 ..$ data :List of 134
 .. ..$ : int 5624
 .. ..$ : int 5625
 .. ..$ : int 5627
 .. .. [list output truncated]
 :List of 5
 ..$ type : chr "dist"
 ..$ data :List of 134
 .. ..$ : num 22321
 .. ..$ : num 22313
 .. .. [list output truncated]
 :List of 5
 ..$ type : chr "cad"
 ..$ data :List of 134
 .. ..$ : num 0.4
 .. ..$ : num 0.6
 .. .. [list output truncated]`

This structure is thus replicated for a large number of lists - the objective is to convert this list to a data frame by pulling the "data" portion of all the variables defined by "type" across all the major lists

Note: Other major lists may have more variables ($ type) and higher/lower number of observations with the sublist - i.e. a list of 134 does not apply to the other lists in the Large list.

Thanks in anticipation.
Further update:

Below is the dput result for clarity:

`

```
list(structure(list(type = "time", data = list(2881L, 2885L, 
    2892L, 2893L, 2898L, 2899L, 2900L, 2901L, 2904L, 2907L, 2911L, 
    2912L, 2914L, 2918L), series_type = "distance", original_size = 14L, 
    resolution = "high"), .Names = c("type", "data", "series_type", 
"original_size", "resolution")), structure(list(type = "distance", 
    data = list(22512.4, 22548.3, 22605.5, 22615.1, 22670.3, 
        22692.2, 22705.8, 22719, 22752.3, 22771.7, 22815.6, 22827.9, 
        22851.6, 22892.5), series_type = "distance", original_size = 14L, 
    resolution = "high"), .Names = c("type", "data", "series_type", 
"original_size", "resolution")), structure(list(type = "grade_smooth", 
    data = list(-1.7, -3.1, -3.7, -3.2, -3, -3, -1.4, -2.5, -3.2, 
        -3.6, -3.7, -3.6, -2.7, -2.5)9.7, 10.3, 10.5, 10), 
    series_type = "distance", original_size = 14L, resolution = "high"), .Names = c("type", 
"data", "series_type", "original_size", "resolution")), structure(list(
    type = "time", data = list(665L, 668L, 671L, 674L, 677L, 
        680L, 683L, 686L, 689L, 692L, 695L, 698L, 701L, 704L), 
    series_type = "distance", original_size = 14L, resolution = "high"), .Names = c("type", 
"data", "series_type", "original_size", "resolution")))
```

`
Further Update:

Upon Implementation of solutions provided I end up with a data frame like this:

[Current Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTVki.png)

[Needed Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrhfN.png)

df issue:

str(unlisting)

`List of 11106
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ type         : chr "time"
  ..$ data         : int [1:180] 2426 2429 2432 2435 2438 2441 2445 2448 2451 2454 ...
  ..$ series_type  : chr "distance"
  ..$ original_size: int 180
  ..$ resolution   : chr "high"
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ type         : chr "distance"
  ..$ data         : num [1:180] 8802 8815 8826 8834 8844 ...
  ..$ series_type  : chr "distance"
  ..$ original_size: int 180
  ..$ resolution   : chr "high"
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ type         : chr "grade_smooth"
  ..$ data         : num [1:180] -1 -0.7 -0.6 -0.4 -0.2 -0.1 0 0.2 0.4 0.5 ...
  ..$ series_type  : chr "distance"
  ..$ original_size: int 180
  ..$ resolution   : chr "high"
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ type         : chr "velocity_smooth"
  ..$ data         : num [1:180] 2.7 3.9 3.9 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.6 4.4 4.5 3 ...
  ..$ series_type  : chr "distance"
  ..$ original_size: int 180
  ..$ resolution   : chr "high"
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ type         : chr "time"
  ..$ data         : int [1:74] 2999 3008 3009 3016 3020 3026 3027 3029 3030 3036 ...
  ..$ series_type  : chr "distance"
  ..$ original_size: int 74
  ..$ resolution   : chr "high"
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ type         : chr "distance"
  ..$ data         : num [1:74] 23661 23719 23735 23790 23825 ...
  ..$ series_type  : chr "distance"
  ..$ original_size: int 74
  ..$ resolution   : chr "high"
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ type         : chr "grade_smooth"
  ..$ data         : num [1:74] -1.3 -0.5 -0.5 0.6 0.7 1 1 0.5 1 1.9 ...
  ..$ series_type  : chr "distance"
  ..$ original_size: int 74
  ..$ resolution   : chr "high"
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ type         : chr "velocity_smooth"
  ..$ data         : num [1:74] 5.7 6.2 7.4 8.9 8.2 8.6 8.2 8.3 8.2 9.2 ...
  ..$ series_type  : chr "distance"
  ..$ original_size: int 74
  ..$ resolution   : chr "high"
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ type         : chr "time"
  ..$ data         : int [1:60] 396 403 410 416 418 424 429 437 447 455 ...
  ..$ series_type  : chr "distance"
  ..$ original_size: int 60
  ..$ resolution   : chr "high"
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ type         : chr "distance"
  ..$ data         : num [1:60] 935 964 992 1014 1020 ...
  ..$ series_type  : chr "distance"
  ..$ original_size: int 60
  ..$ resolution   : chr "high"
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ type         : chr "heartrate"
  ..$ data         : int [1:60] 121 117 117 111 108 107 109 112 116 121 ...
  ..$ series_type  : chr "distance"
  ..$ original_size: int 60
  ..$ resolution   : chr "high"
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ type         : chr "grade_smooth"
  ..$ data         : num [1:60] -0.7 -0.5 -0.3 0.1 0.4 0.8 1 0.9 1.4 1.6 ...
  ..$ series_type  : chr "distance"
  ..$ original_size: int 60
  ..$ resolution   : chr "high"
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ type         : chr "velocity_smooth"
  ..$ data         : num [1:60] 3 4 4.1 3.8 3.4 2.8 3.4 5.2 6.2 6.7 ...
  ..$ series_type  : chr "distance"
  ..$ original_size: int 60
  ..$ resolution   : chr "high" 
  [list output truncated]`

Comment: Is there anyway you can provide us with an example portion of the complex list? perhaps by pasting the results of `dput(mylist)` or by making a smaller one?

Comment: When it comes to nested lists, coming to a solution without really knowing every repetitive detail of your list structure is realllly difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run some of this code, let me know what is different in your data frame and I will edit more to help:

```
# fake data
a <- list(type = "time", data = vector("list", 134), foo3 = vector("list", 134), foo4 = vector("list",134), foo5 = vector("list",134))
names(b)
b <- list(type = "dist", data = vector("list", 134), foo3 = vector("list", 134), foo4 = vector("list",134), foo5 = vector("list",134))

c <- list(type = "cad", data = vector("list", 134), foo3 = vector("list", 134), foo4 = vector("list",134), foo5 = vector("list",134))
example <- list(a, b, c)

# populate some fake data
for(i in 1:length(example)){
  L <- length(example[[i]])
  for(j in 1:L){
    if(j == 1){ 
      example[[i]][[j]] <- c("time","dist","cad")[i]
    } else {
      example[[i]][[j]] <- rep(list(as.numeric(i+j)),134)
    }
  }
}

# unlist function on the right level of nested list
unlisting <- lapply(example, function(L1) lapply(L1, unlist))
str(unlisting)

listsofDFs <- lapply(unlisting, function(L1) as.data.frame(L1))
str(listsofDFs)

listsofDFs
```

**EDIT:**

```
df <- do.call(rbind,listsofDFs)
df.split <- split(df$data, df$type)
maxLength <- max(rapply(df.split, length))
df2.split <- vector("list", length(df.split))
z <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(df.split)){
  z <- df.split[[i]]
  length(z) <- maxLength
  df2.split[[i]] <- z
}
df2 <- do.call(cbind.data.frame,df2.split)
colnames(df2) <- names(df.split)
copyrows <- match(df2$time, df$data)
df2.final <- cbind.data.frame(df2,df[copyrows, -which(names(df) %in% c("type","data"))])
df2.final

head(df2.final)
  #time distance grade_smooth velocity_smooth heartrate series_type original_size resolution
#1 2881  22512.4         -1.7             7.6       110    distance            14       high
#2 2885  22548.3         -3.1             8.5       114    distance            14       high
#3 2892  22605.5         -3.7             8.5       118    distance            14       high
#4 2893  22615.1         -3.2             8.3       122    distance            14       high
#5 2898  22670.3         -3.0            10.8       132    distance            14       high
#6 2899  22692.2         -3.0            10.8       139    distance            14       high
tail(df2.final)
    #time distance grade_smooth velocity_smooth heartrate series_type original_size resolution
#135  689       NA           NA              NA        NA    distance            14       high
#136  692       NA           NA              NA        NA    distance            14       high
#137  695       NA           NA              NA        NA    distance            14       high
#138  698       NA           NA              NA        NA    distance            14       high
#139  701       NA           NA              NA        NA    distance            14       high
#140  704       NA           NA              NA        NA    distance            14       high
```

Comment: Thanks for the above code! It almost simulates the structure but it isn't fully the same - it doesn't account for the multiple lists of the sublists - The output gotten is for one of the many lists available, potentially creating multiple lists of dfs - I am hoping the dput sample result I've provided would help your understanding - many thanks!

Comment: On further implementation of your code, coupled with the rbindlist function, I was able to convert it all into a single df! however, the problem now is that the data is listed in such a way that all the variable names are outlined in rows with the corresponding data in the second column - I will like to transpose this so that for all the rows with variable x it creates a new column with var-x and the corresponding data; var-y and the corresponding data in a new column and so on...

Comment: do.call(rbind,listsofDFs) would put it all in one df! Let me read what you are saying as I am a little confused

Comment: Thanks ever so much! I have added images of what I currently have vis-a-vis what I need, for clarity.

Comment: Ah, the issue here is that you don't have an even number of each type

Comment: I get your point, but each set of list have the same number of obs for all the variables so it should reconcile. However, yes, some lists do not have data for certain variables...can that be classed as 'na' to maintain the structure?

Comment: Okay if you run `df <- do.call(rbind,listsofDFs) ; x <- split(df$data, df$type) ; lapply(x, length)` you will see what I mean. Yes I can fill NAs in for you, one moment

Comment: My absolute pleasure - if you'd like to close this question and mark this answer as correct, please use the check mark on the left! Cheers!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again - I tried the code `listsofDFs <- lapply(unlisting, function(L1) as.data.frame(L1))` on a similar example list after the initial unlisting and got this error: ** Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0 ** please advise - thanks! @Evan

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response - I have edited my post as requested.

Comment: Wow! That's big! So the format doesn't seem different, `lapply(unlisting, function(L1) as.data.frame(L1))` should work... I notice it goes from lists that would make a dataframe with 60 rows to those with over 300 rows. This should not be an issue with the code however...

Comment: I know! @big, should have truncated it a bit more...but wanted you to have enough info to identify the possible issue. I have tried it again - same error. Could it be that one of the elements in the list is causing the problem?

Comment: To investigate further, I removed certain elements (between 1000 - 2000) from the total and ran it on the remaining set, and it worked - I suspect there is a problem with some elements in that range.

Comment: Nice detective work, going to have to narrow down what is causing it. Try seeing if `finderror <- list() ; for(i in 1:length(unlisting)) finderror[[i]] <- tryCatch( as.data.frame(unlisting[[i]]) , error = function(e) "CHECKHERE", warning = function(w) i) ` spots anything? I haven't tested the line but tell me what happenes. The code is supposed to run even if there are errors, instead of stopping if there is an error it should warn you the element number and fill in "CHECKHERE" as the value instead.

Comment: With that, it worked on all the elements! wow..:) the problematic item is element 1842!!

Comment: but does `which("CHECKHERE" %in% finderror)` give you any numbers?

Comment: Yes, and I discovered the problematic element as a result! Thanks ever so much!

Comment: Cheers~ any more questions feel free to comment or start a new question