# How to convert a large list dataset to a data frame dataset in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

I am making a basic machine learning model in R. I am using `tissue_gene_expression` dataset in `dslabs` package which is large list. I used datasets which were data frames until now and I was able to run a very basic code like this:

```
library(caret)
library(rpart)
library(dslabs)
data("any_dataset_here")

set.seed(1)
fit <- train(y ~ x, method = "rpart", tuneGrid = data.frame(cp = seq(0, 0.1, 0.01)), data = any_dataset_here)
plot(fit)
```

But when I tried this method with `tissue_gene_expression`, I got an error:

```
Error in data[0, cols, drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I can fix this error but then another error happens.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942760/most-efficient-list-to-data-frame-method?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740312/converting-a-large-list-of-lists-with-data-points-listed-in-lists-into-a-data) and many more methods but they didn't work. Then, I divided the dataset by x and y and merged them as data frames but it didn't work too. The code was this:

```
x <- tissue_gene_expression$x
y <- tissue_gene_expression$y
data <- merge(as.data.frame(x), as.data.frame(y))
```

I tried different approaches to fix this problem but I couldn't get it and I am stuck here. I think there should be an easy solution. I need help at this point.

---

A sample of the [`dslabs`](https://github.com/cran/dslabs/blob/master/data/tissue_gene_expression.rda) dataset:

```r
tissue_samp <- list(x = structure(c(9.82567961156526, 9.63124675443192, 9.6905477405041, 8.32716269991154, 8.54282675765235, 8.47648576924408, 5.49938189571546, 5.64429228822371, 5.71718693776275, 8.69237073974266, 8.83367868047273, 8.49862302902272), dim = 3:4, dimnames = list(c("cerebellum_1", "cerebellum_2", "cerebellum_3"), c("MAML1", "LHPP", "SEPT10", "B3GNT4"))), y = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("cerebellum", "colon", "endometrium", "hippocampus", "kidney", "liver", "placenta"), class = "factor"))
```

While this sample has `x` of 3x4 and `y` length-3, the real is

```r
str(tissue_gene_expression)
# List of 2
#  $ x: num [1:189, 1:500] 9.83 9.63 9.69 9.99 9.58 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. ..$ : chr [1:189] "cerebellum_1" "cerebellum_2" "cerebellum_3" "cerebellum_4" ...
#   .. ..$ : chr [1:500] "MAML1" "LHPP" "SEPT10" "B3GNT4" ...
#  $ y: Factor w/ 7 levels "cerebellum","colon",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: It is very hard to troubleshoot issues with the structure of your data without you sharing what your data looks like. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I think it's https://github.com/cran/dslabs/blob/master/data/tissue_gene_expression.rda ...

Comment: AG7, I suggested an edit to your question with a sample of that dataset, as a convenience to others. If you don't like me doing this, my apologies, we can roll it back if desired.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you so much, it helps others to understand my dataset better

Comment: Thanks r2evans. I think instead of using the formula interface of `train`, just supply x and y: so `train(x = tissue_gene_expression$x, y = tissue_gene_expression$y, .....)`. See `?train`.

Comment: @Axeman's suggestion works for me with only a small warning (not shown by default, it's about a partial match in some internal code ... likely ignorable). Axeman, perhaps post as an answer?

Comment: @Axeman this is the console when I do that:
Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :11    NA's   :11   
Error: Stopping
In addition: There were 26 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a regular `caret` user, so not sure why that is. For me this work totally fine, with a fresh install of `caret`: `fit <- train(x = tissue_gene_expression$x, y = tissue_gene_expression$y, method = "rpart", tuneGrid = data.frame(cp = seq(0, 0.1, 0.01)))`

Comment: @Axeman oh, sorry you are right. I forgot deleting `data = tissue_gene_expression` it works fine now. Thank you

Comment: Ah sorry, probably should have mentioned that! Glad it is all working now.

Comment: Title of the question probably should be "How to train a machine learning model with non-data frame dataset in R?"

Answer (score -1):

With `tissue_samp`, we could convert it to a flat table using:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_cols(as_tibble(tissue_samp$x, rownames = "rownames"),
          y = tissue_samp$y)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  rownames     MAML1  LHPP SEPT10 B3GNT4 y         
  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>     
1 cerebellum_1  9.83  8.33   5.50   8.69 cerebellum
2 cerebellum_2  9.63  8.54   5.64   8.83 cerebellum
3 cerebellum_3  9.69  8.48   5.72   8.50 cerebellum
```